# What does "dot" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

My first language is Spanish and I can't understand this question about a book (The butterfly lion):

> What dot did he have at school?

The story is about a kid who have some troubles in school with his professor and colleagues, that's all what I can say after reading two pages.

Does the term 'dot' make sense here? Or is a mistake? I'm sure this is not referring to the school marks.

Comment: Offer some more context, please.

Comment: Done, that's all what I can say.

Comment: It would help if you could excerpt the sentences preceding this one, and indicate what book or at least what kind of book you have found it in.

Comment: The question isn't in the book, it was made by a teacher as a homework (not for me, of course). Book name: The butterfly lion.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense without context. It may be a local term that the author is introducing without defining to give the reader a sense of otherness. This is common in science fiction, for instance.

Comment: Without more context this question seems pointless.

Comment: Is it perhaps a typo, and is asking "what dog did he have at school"?

Comment: It's not a pointless question to a non-English speaker, but it is nonsensical English without more information.

Comment: Which other information can I bring to you? I leave the book name in my previous comment. That's all what I have. @long I don't think so...

Comment: I've read the first chapter and a few pages into the second (whatever Amazon lets me read for free) [far enough that he has run away from school, met a woman and apparently started on his adventure] and a ***dot*** makes no sense. It's got to be a typo in your teacher's material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely a mistake if the question is referring to the narrator's experience (in the first chapter). The word *dot* was probably supposed to be *diet* ("of Latin and stew and rugby and..."). There are not dots of any sort, real or metaphorical, to be found in the chapter.